# Can we make multiple google play accounts in same ip address?

Tags: android, console, google-play, playback

I signed up for a Google play developer console account from Lenovo laptop in feb 20 2016. after one year i bought a new laptop and for some reason my developer account got suspended on  oct 10 2017 which was signed in on my new laptop and on the next day i.e oct 11 2017 I signed up for a new developer account with a same laptop in which the old one got suspended but with different email, credit card & internet connection. Is this ok or my new developer account will also be suspended? i just published some new apps their 1 week ago

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can create multiple google play account on same IP  but you will have to pay the $25 developer fee again.the only things you have to remember just use different email id for different accounts , in this case you have to make concern about this if you will make any mistake your all accounts can be in danger.

Comment: When i emailed google to reinstating my developer account. I got this in reply. is it mean that i can't make more accounts on same ip?


"Google Play Developer account terminations are associated with developers and may span multiple account registrations and related Google services. Do not attempt to register a new developer account. Any new accounts will be closed and your developer registration fee will not be refunded. We recommend that you use an alternative method for distributing your apps in the future."

Comment: You can refer this link for more clarification https://play.google.com/intl/en_us/about/play-terms.html

Answer (score 0):

Take this from someone who suffered from the unfair google play developer account terminations 
Once your first account is terminated 
every single account you opened will be terminated within months in a maximum.
It's just how things are with Google